# 'undefined likes' twitter like project

Tags: javascript, python, django

Recently I started working on a twitter like clone to learn some python and django. I have successfully added "tweets" and got them to display some basic text on my homepage. My issue is with the like button. I am attempting to have a like button that will display the total amount of likes on that "tweet". For now I am using a random int just to display the likes. However the button just displays "undefined Likes". I thought it was going to be pretty straight forward however i am still new to all this so any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks all.

views.py:

```
import random
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Prediction

# Create your views here.
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "pages/home.html", context={}, status=200)


def prediction_list_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    REST API VIEW
    Consume by JavaScript or Swift/Java/iOS/Andriod
    return json data
    """
    qs = Prediction.objects.all()
    predictions_list = [{"id": x.id, "content": x.content, "likes": random.randint(0, 122)} for x in qs]
    data = {
        "isUser": False,
        "response": predictions_list
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)


def prediction_detail_view(request, prediction_id, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    REST API VIEW
    Consume by JavaScript or Swift/Java/iOS/Andriod
    return json data
    """
    data = {
        "id": prediction_id,
    }
    status = 200
    try:
        obj = Prediction.objects.get(id=prediction_id)
        data['content'] = obj.content
    except:
        data['message'] = "Not found"
        status = 404
    return JsonResponse(data, status=status) # json.dumps content_type='application/json' 







_____________________________________________________________________________________

↓↓↓↓ This is my home.html ↓↓↓↓

_____________________________________________________________________________________



{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head_title %}
Welcome
{% endblock head_title%}


{% block content %}
Welcome

<div id='predictions'>
    Loading...
</div>

<script>
const predictionsElement = document.getElementById("predictions") // get an html element

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
const method = 'GET' // "POST"
const url = "/predictions"
const responseType = "json"


function handleDidLike (prediction_id, currentCount) {
    console.log(prediction_id, currentCount)
    return 
}

function LikeBtn(prediction) {
    return "<button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' onclick=handleDidLike(" + 
    prediction.id + "," + prediction.likes + ")>" + prediction.likes + " Likes</button>"
}

function formatPredictionElement(prediction) {
    var formattedPrediction = "<div class='mb-4 prediction' id='prediction-" + prediction.id 
    + "'><p>" + prediction.content + 
        "</p><div class='btn-group'>" + LikeBtn(prediction) +
        "</div></div>"
    return formattedPrediction
}
xhr.responseType = responseType
xhr.open(method, url)
xhr.onload = function() {
    const serverResponse = xhr.response
    const listedItems = serverResponse.response // array
    var finalPredictionStr = ""
    var i;
    for (i=0;i<listedItems.length; i++) {
        var predictionObj = listedItems[i]
        var currentItem = formatPredictionElement(predictionObj)
        finalPredictionStr += currentItem
    }
    predictionsElement.innerHTML = finalPredictionStr
}
xhr.send()


</script>
{% endblock content %}
```